# pandas convert series of ndarrays to dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series `S` of 263 elements, each is a `ndarray` with the shape `1X768`.
I need to convert it to dataframe. So, the dataframe should have the shape `263X768` and include the actual data from `S`.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack`:

```
# list of ndarrays
x = [np.ones((1, 768)) for x in range(263)]

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(x))
df.shape
```

Output:

```
(263, 768)
```

Comment: But it is all ones.. I want the actual data from my series, please see my edit

Comment: I used `np.ones` as an example. Of course, you should use your `ndarrays` instead of that. If they are elements of `pd.Series` called `S`, then you can do `df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(S))`